# maintain session in windows mobile app

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am developing windows mobile application using .net framework 3.5(visual studio 2008).I need to use static variables in mobile app like session in website.Below code is for my login form and insde the login form i used a static method and declared a static variable.Please see below code.

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
    private void btnSubmit_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    var username = txtUsername.Text;
    var password = txtPassword.Text;
    //do some other task with username & password
    }
    public static class loginInfo
    {
        public static string username;       
    }
}
```

Then i used the same static variable in another page of same application,i can see their is no value in messagebox dialog.See below the code

```
public partial class SettingsForm : Form
{
     private void SettingsControl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
     {
          //other code comes here
          MessageBox.Show(loginInfo.username);
     }
}
```

the above code displays a empty dialog box and it is not showing the username.

I need to save the username locally and check if it is exist, i can allow that settings page otherwise need to hide the sittings page.

Please guide me what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The code `var username = txtUsername.Text;` is setting a local variable to the value in the user name edit control.  This variable goes out of scope as soon as the method completes and is lost forever.

I believe that what you are trying to do is this:

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
    private void btnSubmit_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    loginInfo.username = txtUsername.Text;
    loginInfo.password = txtPassword.Text;
    //do some other task with username & password
    }
    public static class loginInfo
    {
        public static string username;
        public static string password;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with this,i am facing the same problem.Can you please tell me to solve this in any other way.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it to make sure that loginInfo.username actually gets set?